# Celery periodic task not working

Tags: python, django, celery

I tried to follow celery doc for django . Here is my project structure :

```
├── hiren
│   ├── celery_app.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── reminder
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   |── task.py
│   |── tests.py
│   |── views.py
```

here is my settings.py file:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/4'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'run-every-5-seconds': {
        'task': 'reminder.task.run',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

and reminder/task.py  file :

```
def run():
    print('hello')
```

when I run `celery -A hiren beat -l debug` command I didn't see "hello" text in terminal . What I am missing ?

Comment: Have you read: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-shared-task-decorator ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a task from any callable,you need to use the `task()` decorator. This will create a celery task for `run()`.

**reminder/task.py:**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost')

@app.task
def run():
    print('hello')
```

The Celery library must be instantiated before use, this instance is called an application (or `app` for short).

**If you are using the “old” module based celery API, then you can import the task decorator like this:**

```
from celery import task

@task
def run():
    print('hello')
```

Even though this will create a celery task just like first method, but this is not recommended.